# Comparing with 2 possible values

Tags: javascript, syntax, boolean-logic

I have a problem and i dunno how to solve it.

From the code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tiparire_dialog_unu').dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 360,
    resizable: true
});
$(".factchit").hide();

$("#sablon_unu").change((function () {
   valsablon=$("#sablon_unu").val();
   if (valsablon=='5' ) $(".factchit").show();
   else $(".factchit").hide();
}))

$("#acceptprint_unu").click((function () {
   if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5' && $("#nrchitanta").val()=='') {
      eroare(true,eroareatn,'Lipsa numar chitanta');  return false;
   }
   if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5' && $("#seriechit_").val()=='') {
      eroare(true,eroareatn,'Lipsa serie chitanta');  return false;
   }
    var strform_tiparire_unu = $("#form_tiparire_unu").serialize();
    var sendmail=$("#sendmail").val();
    //  alert(strform_tiparire_unu);
    //       return false;
    if (sendmail=="F") {
        jQuery("#iesiridet").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: 'listdoc.php?' + strform_tiparire_unu + '&iddoc=' + iddoc ,tag: 'pdf'});
        }
  else {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "listdoc.php",
            data: strform_tiparire_unu + '&iddoc=' + iddoc,
            success: function (json) {
        eval("json=" + json);
        eval(json.mesaj);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                eroare(true,eroareatn,eroaremsg);  return false;
            }
        }); // ajax
  }
  if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5') setTimeout(function() {  $("#iesiri").trigger("reloadGrid"); },timpout+500);
    jQuery("#tiparire_dialog_unu").dialog("close");
    return false;
})); // clic

});
</script>
```

I am trying to add

```
if (valsablon=='5', '6' ) $(".factchit").show();

if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5', '6' && $("#nrchitanta").val()=='') {

if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5', '6' && $("#seriechit_").val()=='') {
```

and

```
if ($("#sablon_unu").val()=='5', '6') setTimeout(function() {  $("#iesiri").trigger("reloadGrid"); },timpout+500);
```

The 1st code is running perfectly, except that i wanna compare with 2 values dat applies to this code, 5 and 6, not just only 5…
Any help with this?

Comment: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) one of the fine answers you've received here.  You might also consider accepting answers to some of your other past questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for both with either OR (`||`) or AND (`&&`) etc.

```
if ( valsablon == '5' || valsablon == '6' ) 
    $(".factchit").show();

if ( (valsablon == '5' || valsablon == '6') && $("#nrchitanta").val() == '') {
    setTimeout(function() {  
        $("#iesiri").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
    },timpout + 500);
}
```

Another way would be to use an array

```
if ( ['5', '6'].indexOf( valsablon ) != -1 )
    $(".factchit").show();
```

Comment: Yea, this explained the problem, thank you very much for helping me, and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the value is equal to either 5 or 6? You would use an or. And to combine it with the empty check, you need to surround it with parenthesis.

```
var val = $("#sablon_unu").val();
if ( (val=='5' || val == '6') && $("#nrchitanta").val()=='' )
```

Comment: Yes, one of them, not both at the same time. Worked like a charm, tyvm for your time!